# Retain Focus of Edit Text on Orientation Change in Android Activity and Fragment

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to Retain Focus of Edit Text After Orientation Change in Android Activity and Fragment,Any help to achieve this?,For Example After Changing orientation I have to retain focus of Selected Edit Text.See below Pic.

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to show soft keyboard?

Comment: Have you tried `editText.requestFocus()`?

Comment: @MisaghEmamverdi,I tried But not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by saving the focus of your `EditText`, and re-assign it in `onResume()`.

```
EditText et;
static boolean et_focus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  // Your code...

  et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean focus) {
      et_focus = focus;         
    }
  });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  if(et_focus) {
    et.requestFocus();
  }
}
```

Hope this is helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to listen System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION by a content observer.

To register the content observer

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION),true,rotationObserver );
```

The onChange method will be called when the orientation  is changed.

```
private ContentObserver rotationObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
       Do your task
    }
```

};